# gcc compiled library on VS using ext/hash_map

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, static-libraries, header-files

I'd like to use a library I've compiled using Cygwin GCC (.a) in a Visual Studio C++ project. When I include headers from the library in VS, the **ext/hash_map** header is missing. Is that a header file I can just add and replace with hash_map, or is it all together hopeless (because the library doesn't make heavy use of hash maps)? Moreover, is it ridiculous to hope VS can use the .a library? Thanks!

Comment: You need to compile using MinGW GCC. Cygwin compiled libraries have a different format (ELF) than it's consumed by VS (PE). So you can't.

Comment: 1. ext/hash_map - is non standard extension. use unordered_map instead 
2. you need to compile your library with VS (different format, crt, abi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix GCC generated `.a` files with Visual Studio.

Comment: That goes for both MinGW and Cygwin? Thanks

Comment: Yes. It is tricky to even mix the different runtimes from different versions of Visual Studio. Do not try to mix with MinGW and Cygwin.